# What is the appropriate opposite or antonym word for sweet?

Tags: antonyms

A part of my brain says, this is a flavor, how can an opposite exist?

On the other hand my other part of brain says, if opposites can exist for feelings why not for flavors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Opposites are determined by context. The opposite of *man* can be *woman, boy, robot, god, alien, teenager, tsar, plant, animal* — even though a man *is* an animal.

Likewise, "the" opposite for *sweet* can be *bitter*, or *sour*, or *hideous*, or you name it.

Comment: That is a good answer...but what if the context is flavor?

Comment: If the context is flavor, that is still too broad a context, as there are more than two flavors. As I said, *bitter* and *sour* are both candidates, and so is *salty*, and so is *umami*.

Comment: @hawk generally Bitter or Sour... Depending largely on who you ask.

Comment: @RegDwigнt So,actually what you mean is that the antonyms we used to learn in our childhood are actually baseless unless there is any context?

Comment: I don't know what antonyms you learned in your childhood, but yes, I bet you yourself can easily name perfectly valid alternatives for every single one of them.

Comment: The opposite of a *sweet* disposition is a *surly* one — surely. :)

Comment: Many of the opposites we learn as a child are opposites are context sensitive. The opposite of light might be heavy or dark for instance. Cats and dogs are very similar in that they're quadrupedal  mammals but considered "opposites" in most other ways. I am not sure if I agree that all antonyms are contextual though, I can not think of one where black and white are not opposed and that is somewhat objectively based. It probably is true of flavor though, if flavor can be considered to have opposites. Also @tchrist I would probably pick spoiled rotten to keep in line with the food analogy. =P

Comment: @Hawk: Antonym pairs are usually mutually exclusive. I.e. for a pair A and B who are eachother's antonym; B is equal to "not A" and A is equal to "not B".

Answer (score 7):

If you were to ask most English speakers, they would suggest 'sour' or 'bitter' as the opposite of sweet. I would speculate that this is because while sweetness is usually something which appeals to many people, sourness or bitterness are very much acquired tastes (and can even indicate that something is not fit to eat).

The word *bittersweet* indicates the tension between 'bitterness' and 'sweetness', and similarly means an intense feeling in which two opposite feelings, such as happiness and regret, are both present. So if one were to choose a *single* opposite to sweetness, bitterness may *idiomatically* be the safest choice.

However, in reality, the opposite to sweetness is, as `RegDwigнt` indicates, dependent on context, even if you restrict yourself to food and drink.

- In fruit, the opposite of sweet is usually sour.
- In chocolate, the opposite of sweet is bitter.
- In snack-food (e.g. popcorn, nuts, etc.), the opposite of sweet is salty, or savoury.
- In wine, the opposite of sweet is *dry*.

Comment: If I could downvote, I would downvote this answer, as this answer does not provide any extra context but just agrees to the answer given by @RegDwigнt

Comment: @Hawk: why? It indicates that multiple "literal" opposites that are present even in talking about flavour, just as you ask; and indicates a reason to prefer bitterness idiomatically.

Comment: When there is no context to prefer any choice...how can one prefer bitterness? However the literal opposites you said is not that much of a secret to many people...but thanks anyways...you tried to contribute...do not take my criticism personally

Comment: +1 for adding examples of different contexts that would yield different choices for opposites.

Comment: @Hawk: If there is no context to prefer a literal choice, one chooses according to *assumed* context. For example, if I asked you the opposite of "hot", you might say "cold", and for good reason; despite the fact that there are contexts in which "slow" (for jazz) or "unsexy" (for physical aesthetics) are valid antonyms. All language is an association game: there is always a context, if only a vague cultural one. My suggestion of bitterness is on the basis of cultural referents; if you demanded more, perhaps you intended to ask the question on Philosophy.SE.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying, you are saying things as said by @RegDwigнt and not providing any new context to the question...anyways...I always knew subjects excluding mathematics are too controversial to approach...so I drop this discussion here

Answer (score 1):

@Hawk - in the classical liberal arts tradition, there is a distinction made between contraries and contradictories.

**Black** and **white** / **sweet** and **sour** are contraries.
They refer to species within the same genus (black and white are both **colours**), or species in contrary genera (truthfulness is a species of **virtue**; falsity a species of **vice**).

Genera do not have contraries - there is no contrary for flower, and flavour (your example) if taken as a genus, would not have a contrary. 
If taken as a species of sense data, then **flavoursome** and **tasteless** would be contraries.

**Black** and **non-black** / **flavour** and **non-flavour** are contradictories.

If you're interested in pursuing this further, see Sister Miriam Joseph's [The Trivium](http://www.bookfinder.com/search/?author=joseph&title=trivium&lang=en&isbn=&submit=Search&new_used=%2a&destination=gb&currency=GBP&mode=basic&st=sr&ac=qr) (2002), pp 76-77.